# Laravel select box to show the name and save an id of this name

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, web, laravel-5

I have a problem. I want to create a dropdown box with the name's  from a table in my database andstore just an id from that name in other table (that id is a foreign key). I will show you my code

```
//acao model
public function estado() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Estado');
}
//estado model<p>
public function acao()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Acao');
}
```

AcaoController@Create:

```
public function create()
{
  $estado = Estado::pluck('nome', 'id');
  return view('Backoffice.acoes.criar_acao', compact('estado'));
}
```

AcaoController@Store:

```
$data = Acao::create([
      'estado_id' => $data[estado_id],
    ]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This way the store doesn´t work and i think that this code doesn´t work with the relationship beetween acao and estado.

Can anyone help me please
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>If I get it, you want to create an *Acao* Model among whit the *Estado* model.
First of all, you are using `$data[estado_id]` which is not initialized yet.
One simple solution is to create the Acao Object first, then accessing the property estado and create a new Instance of it. then save the model using eloquent:</del>

```
$acao = new \App\Acao([/*your data*/]); // even a create is good
$acao->save();                         // instead of save  
$acao->estado()->create(
    [/*estado data*/]
); 
$acao->save();
```

<del>I'm *not* sure what you are trying to achieve passing `$data[estado_id]` to the create method.</del>

### Edit

View

```
<select name="estado">
    @foreach($estdo in $estados)
        <option value="{{ $estado->id }}">{{$estado->nome}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Controller

```
Acao::create([
   'estado_id' => $request->get('estado'),
]);
```

Or

```
$acao = new Acao;
$acao->estado_id = $request->get('estado');
$acao->save();
```

Comment: i am not sure if you understand my problem. i have a form to create a acao and store in my database. one of the fields of my form is estado (dropdown). estado is another table with some content (id, name etc...). what i want is when i use a form to create a acao, when i select estado, the options are the content(name) of my estado table. When i do the store has i have a relationship with foreign key (estado_id) on the table acao, i want a query to save the id, not the name althought the user just see the name related with id

Comment: So, you should have something like:
 `<option value="{{estado->id}}">{{estado->name}}</option>`
In the backend, you will be able to create acao with:
`acao::create(['estado' => request->get("<name of the select>"))`
which will give you the selected option value attribute